# Rails path helper for namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a simple Rails application for the sake of debugging which has the following `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :ethan_is_cool do
    scope path: "/:message" do
      get "/go_big", to: "transformations#uppercase"
    end
    get "/profile", to: "profile#index"
    get "/users/:id", to: "users#show"
  end
end
```

When I run `rails routes`, I get the following:

```
               Prefix Verb URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
 ethan_is_cool_go_big GET  /ethan_is_cool/:message/go_big(.:format) ethan_is_cool/transformations#uppercase
ethan_is_cool_profile GET  /ethan_is_cool/profile(.:format)         ethan_is_cool/profile#index
        ethan_is_cool GET  /ethan_is_cool/users/:id(.:format)       ethan_is_cool/users#show
```

This means that there is an `ethan_is_cool_path` which refers for some reason to the last route:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.ethan_is_cool_path(id: 1)
=> "/ethan_is_cool/users/1"
```

Is this behavior correct or is it a bug? I might have expected `ethan_is_cool_users_path`, but not `ethan_is_cool_path`. `ethan_is_cool` is the name of a namespace, and it doesn't really make sense for it to have a route.

If this behavior is correct, can you point me to some documentation that explains it? I've read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html but it mostly focuses on resourceful routes and it isn't especially clear what controls the names of helper methods.

Comment: I just wanted to get a sanity check before filing a bug since I'm not really a Rails expert. If it seems like a bug, I'm happy to file it!

Comment: As a long time user of rails (I wouldn't dare to call myself an expert), I can confirm that this is indeed eyebrow-raising behaviour.

Comment: Bug. But you may use `resources :users, only: :show` it generates correct prefix `ethan_is_cool_user`.

Comment: Also `get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :users`. However this is definitely report-worthy, it is either just some limitation of the routing system or indeed a bug.

Comment: Thanks everyone who responded. I filed https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42841. I posted that as an answer but it was downvoted and deleted, so I reproduce it as a comment.